# "Partition" of Chi-Square Table

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

How to tell if a specific cell from my 2x2 (also 2x2x2) contingency table (constructed for computing Chi-Square test of independence) is in favor or against the null hypothesis?

Comment: Make a table of residuals and look at that. If the table is high-dimensional, I would complementing with a correspondence analysis.   Or, if you are looking for a few extreme cells in very large contingency tables, google for "Identifying extreme cells in a sizable contingency table"  (without the quotes).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the quick reply! I found this http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~dipankar/bmtry711.11/lecture_10.pdf (page 7/30) However, it only talks about a "rule of thumb" (page 8/30), in contrast I am looking for some statistical method to infer if the cell is in favor or against the null hypothesis.

Comment: I have finally found the answer. Page 2 (Calculating Residuals) of http://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=20&n=8

Answer (score 2):

Make a table of residuals and look at that. If the table is high-dimensional, I would complementing with a correspondence analysis. Or, if you are looking for a few extreme cells in very large contingency tables, google for "Identifying extreme cells in a sizable contingency table" (without the quotes). For example [jstor: Detecting Outlying Cells in Two-Way Contingency Tables Via Backwards-Stepping](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1270088).

For an example of such residuals see [Interpreting residuals in chi-squared test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495904/interpreting-residuals-in-chi-squared-test)